# python numpy ndarray subclassing for offset changing

Tags: python, numpy, subclass, offset

I am working on a framework for processing incoming data.

The data is received from a socket and added to numpy an array A (used as buffer) using shifting, sth like:

```
A[:-1] = A[1:]
A[-1] = value
```

The framework allows loading processing units as classes that have an access to incoming data using array view pointing to A. Everytime new data is received and stored in A, a method `execute()` is called:

```
def execute(self,):
    newSample = self.data[-1]
```

What is important is that new sample is always under `index = -1`.
A user can also create his own array views in `__init__` function:

```
def __init__(self,):
    self.myData = self.data[-4:]  # view that contains last 4 samples
```

Everything works nicely when I am shifting array A and adding new value at the end. However, for offline testing, I want to load all the data at the start of the framework and run everything else as before (i.e. the same classes implementing data processing). 
Of course, I can again create A buffer using zeros array and shift it with new values. However, this involves copying of data between two arrays that is absolutely not necessary - takes time and memory.

What I was thinking about is to provide a way to change the boundaries of the numpy array or change A.data pointer. However, all the solutions are not allowed or lead to the warning message.

Finally, I am trying to change an internal offset of array A, so that I can advance it and thus make more data available for algorithms. What is important, `self.data[-1]` has to always point to the newly appeared sample and standard numpy array API should be used.

I have subclassed np.ndarray:

```
class MyArrayView(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        # add the new attribute to the created instance
        obj._offset = 0
        # Finally, we must return the newly created object:
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None:
            return
        self._offset = getattr(obj, '_offset', None)

    def advance_index(self):
        self._offset += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return super(MyArrayView, self[:]).__str__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return super(MyArrayView, self[:]).__repr__()

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if isinstance(idx, slice):
            start = 0
            stop = self._offset
            step = idx.step
            idx = slice(start, stop, step)
        else:
            idx = self._offset + idx
        return super(MyArrayView, self).__getitem__(idx)
```

that allows me to do the following:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
myA = MyArrayView(a)
b = myA
print("b :", b)
for i in range(1,5):
    myA.advance_index()
    print(b[:], b[-1])

print("b :", b)
print("b + 10 :", b + 10)
print("b[:] + 20 :", b[:] + 20)
```

and gives following output:

```
b : []
[1] 1
[1 2] 2
[1 2 3] 3
[1 2 3 4] 4
b : [1 2 3 4]
b + 10 : [11 12 13 14]
b[:] + 20 : [21 22 23 24]
```

so far so good. However if I check the shape:

```
print("shape", b[:].shape)  # shape (4,)
print("shape", b.shape)     # shape (10,)
```

it is different in those two cases. I have tried to change it using: `shape=(self.internalIndex,)` but it leads me only to an error message.

I want to ask if you think this is the right way what I am doing and it only requires to overload more functions in a np.ndarray class. Or should I completely abandon this solution and fallback to shifting array with a new sample? Or is it may be possible to be achieved using standard np.ndarray implementation as I need to use standard numpy API.

I also tried this:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
b = a.view()[5:]

print(a.data)  # <memory at 0x7f09e01d8f48>
print(b.data)  # <memory at 0x7f09e01d8f48> They point to the same memory start!

print(np.byte_bounds(a)) # (50237824, 50237904)
print(np.byte_bounds(b)) # (50237864, 50237904) but the byte_bounds are different
```

So having this in mind, I would say I need to create a view of array `a` and extend it (or at least move it like a window on top of `a`).
However, all my tries to change the byte_bounds did not bring any effects.

Answer (score 1):

I admire your bravery, but am quite sure sub-classing numpy arrays is overkill for your problem and can cause you a huge lot of headache. In the end it might cause a performance hit somewhere that by far outruns the array copying you are trying to avoid.

Why not make the slice (i.e. `[-4:]` or `slice(-4, None)`) a parameter to your `__init__` function or a class attribute and override that in your test?

```
def __init__(self, lastfour=slice(-4, None)):
    self.myData = self.data[lastfour]
```